# UICollectionView on UIScrollView freezes

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have an UIViewController, which contains UIScrollView, which contains a few elements, including UICollectionView. UICollectionView is used to display N buttons in fixed frame. UICollectionView scrolling is disabled. Still, my UIScrollView scrolls not as smoothly as it scrolls without UICollectionView. What my be the problem? Does it have something to do with reusable cells?

code:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 9
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("tagsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TagsCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.tagsButton.setTitle("Test", forState: .Normal)
    cell.tagsButton.sizeToFit()
    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize
{
    let element = "Test" as NSString
    let stringSize = element.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)])
    return CGSize(width: stringSize.width + 25, height: 29)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the frame of the scrollView and collectionView is same then it must be a problem to differentiate, which one to call. May be that is why it's creating an issue with the collectionView.

Comment: scroll view height is about 1000, while collection view is 150, width is the same

Comment: then it will not create an issue. Can you post the whole code? The above one is only for collectionView.

Comment: have you set the property of scrollView contentSize.

Comment: This view controller at this point has 300 lines of code (it has 3 tableviews, but everything worked fine with them), if you need something specific I can post it. no, I've not, what value should it be? My view controller height?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? If you are then you don't need to set it. But if your aren't using AutoLayout. Set the contentSize of your scrollView as the height of your scrollView + 250